# How to create Go appllication in sam in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am trying to build and test locally go "hello world" lambda example in VS Code.
In future I would like to test my lambdas and API Gateway locally.

go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64.

sam cli - SAM CLI, version 1.15.0

After ctrl+shift+p > "Creat new SAM application", there is no "golang" option in the list. This is complete list of options (dotnet, node and python).

[image]

I know it should be there (1min 32 sec)
[aws SAM golang examle presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FINV-VmCXms&t=92s)

How to choose go?

Comment: Did you install the Go VS Code plugin? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go

Comment: Yes, I have Go 0.20.1 extension, Go Doc 1.0.1 and AWS Toolkit 1.18.0 all of them was installed earlier, thx for tip.

Comment: According to the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-run-debug-no-template.html it doesn't appear that there is support for running and debuging lambda functions directly from vscode. I suspect what you saw in the video may have been a beta version or perhaps a custom build.

Comment: use up/down arrows? (I suspect maybe there is  a scrollbar accidently hidden from that drop drown pane)

Comment: petey I did try up/down this is complete list, Grizzle I am afraid You are right, I saw this link earlier, I would like to create go app at least.